# Erlang - Download file from url

Tags: erlang

I am trying to download a file from a link. Now I am doing it in the following way:

```
inets:start();
Response = httpc:request(get, {Link, []}, [], []),
  case Response of
    {ok, {{_, 200, "OK"}, Headers, Body}} ->
      file:write_file("dir/filename", Body);
    _ ->
      io:format("Error~n")
  end.
```

Everything is ok and working. But, I am not sure if it is the best way. For large files `httpc:request` is locking and there is no info about what is going on with request. Is there a better way for downloading a file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use one of HTTP options named [Chunked transfer encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding) which [ibrowse](https://github.com/cmullaparthi/ibrowse) library supports it.
[Here](https://github.com/cmullaparthi/ibrowse/blob/v4.4.0/src/ibrowse.erl#L263) is a link of documentation for using ibrowse v4.4.0 with chunked transfer encoding.